# Factory work schedule chain

Tags: python, analytics, data-visualization, data-science

I am new to data science. I want to create python visualisation with car factory work schedules data. This is the requirement:

## 1: example chain A - workA1-->workA2-->workA3-->workA4-->workA5-->workAN (A1 to AN total works)

```
example chain B - workB1-->workB2-->workB3-->workB4-->workB5-->workBN
```

(B1 to BN total works)
    example chain A/B - workA1-->workB2, workB4-->workA6, etc, etc (take into account for any/all such combinations whether there is combination or no)

## 2: There are A,B,C,D,E type works. All A,B,C,D,E works must complete to finish manufacture of a car

## 3: All works must complete in sequence in the chain. Works on right side of arrow cannot start before complete the works on left side of arrow. For examples in the above chain, workB2 cannot start before complete workB1, workA3 cannot start before complete workA2, workA6 cannot start before complete workB4, etc etc..

## 4: The main data contain only 2 columns. First column is preceding_work. Second column is succeeding_work.

Can you please help me teach how to write python code to create interactive visualisations? I can also want to zoom out & zoom in and also click on work to see more details for that work (total hours to complete work, total people to complete work, total number of succeeding_works, total number of preceding_works, etc etc). I am self learning Python by myself. Data table format is below here. Thank you.

+---------------------------------------+
| preceding_work        succeeding_work |
+---------------------------------------+
| A1                    A2              |
| B1                    A2              |
| B1                    B2              |
| A2                    A3              |
| C1                    C2              |
| C2                    B3              |
| B2                    B3              |
| ..                    ..              |
| ..                    ..              |
| ..                    ..              |
| ..                    ..              |
| ..                    ..              |
+---------------------------------------+

Comment: Voting to close - this question is way too broad.

Answer (score 0):

What you are talking about is a directed network graph.  You can use NetworkX to build the graph (how a thing moves through the network).  However the moving of things and the state they are in currently, you are going to have to build on your own.